# insert ₹ in python Django mysql. i'm using frontend react and backend Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hi There when i was entering ₹ in a textfield i'm getting

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE2\\x82\\xB9' for column 'sk_ver_reason' at row 1")
```

this textfield is a description box, mysql acception other countries curreny sign but not in indian currency, i have chages much collation from utf8mb...

when i hit api this sign failed, but the entry for this api enter in db, same i hit again it run succefully, is it python django error or purely mysql db error.

in below image you can see collation of that perticualr field.

[image]

```
reporter_data = {
            'org_id': org_id,
            'email_id' : data['email'],
            'first_name' : data['first_name'],
            'last_name' : data['last_name'],
            'individual_enterprise_government' : individual_enterprise_government,
            'company_individual_address' : company_individual_address,
            'mobile' : mobile,
            'phone' : phone,
            'fax' : fax,
            'comp_individual_country': country,
            'comp_individual_state' : state,
            'comp_individual_city' : city,
            'comp_individual_pin' : comp_individual_pin,
            'company_url': company_url,
            'company_name': company_name,
            'sector_name': sector,
            'sub_sector_name': sub_sector,
            'other_sector_name' : other_sector_name,
            'organization_type':organization_type,
            'organization_severity': organization_severity,
            'informed_email_id' : informed_email_id,
            'informed_email_id_cc1' : informed_email_id_cc1,
            'informed_email_id_cc2' : informed_email_id_cc2,
            'informed_email_id_cc3' : informed_email_id_cc3,
            'user':userdata,
            'is_verified':True
        }
        if 'sk_ver_reason' in list_of_items:
            reporter_data.update({'sk_ver_reason':data['sk_ver_reason']})
        print("DATAATTTATATTt", reporter_data)
        
        ReporterDetails.objects.create(**reporter_data)
```

i'm getting reporter_data all data when i print, but while ORM create run it fail when sk_ver_reason field have  ₹ currency.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from your mysql server and not from django-orm.

This seems to be happening because your database is not cofigured to support `utf8` character set. The rupee symbol needs to be stored as `utf8`.

For rupee you need only 3 byte unicode representation for which you can use the following alter command in mysql to provide the database support.

`ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

If you are expecting more unicode characters to be supported consider enabling support for 4 byte characters as well.

```
-- Change a database
ALTER DATABASE [database_name] 
  CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 

-- Change a table
ALTER TABLE [table_name] 
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 

-- Change a column
ALTER TABLE [table_name] 
  CHANGE [column_name] [column_name] VARCHAR(255) 
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Read more at: https://sebhastian.com/mysql-incorrect-string-value/